# Where do I ask questions about hiring programmers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wanted some pointers on hiring programmers to create and maintain company websites ([see my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150173/abel)).

FAQs:

Q. Why don't you get a proper consultant/programmer and other nay saying questions?

A. The problem is that I cannot afford to get ripped off by a *consultant* before getting ripped off by the wrong guys for the job.

Too much negativity aside, can I ask questions about what to look for in a programmer's resume if I am trying to develop a certain kind of web application on programmers.SE? Or is there a better place to ask?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The original answer was out-of-date as @[RobertColumbia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/336163/robert-columbia) pointed out, here are the actual sites you can visit for such questions:

- onStartUps moved to http://www.brightjourney.com/
- [the Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) has a tag related to [recruitment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruitment).

***Original Answer:***
If you are part of a startup, [onStartUps](http://answers.onstartups.com/) might also be a place where you could investigate, but otherwise, programmers.se seems perfect.