# What happened to OnStartups?

Tags: discussion

I have accidentially stepped into [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74851/189165), but clicking the link inside it makes me hit the wall.

What happened to OnStartups (and when)?

<sub>There's a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153084/189165) on what happened to meta.onstartup.com, but it does not explain, what happend to the main site and it seems to be asked during normal site operation, about some temporal problem.</sub>

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217793/will-there-be-a-replacement-for-onstartups-site?s=3|1.5034)

Comment: I updated my answer with current and relevant links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was [closed a while back](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12607/99336) due to lack of regular users. However, a new startups site has since been created and has been in beta for, as of the time of posting this answer, 295 days, which you can find at https://startups.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: looks like the new link has also closed down

Answer (score 6):

It was [closed down](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) over a year ago, on December 11, 2013. According to an [answer on Area 51 Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now/13094#13094) the site was revived externally on a new domain. There's also an [answer below that](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now/12630#12630) explaining why it was closed down in the first place.